# JavaScript strange behaviour when using PostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I’m having some troubles related to JavaScript in my web application. The code is actually simple, I just want to create a certain number of buttons using the command asp:Repeater and, in case of button click events, open a pdf file in a new tab.  I’m using the follow code to do that:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="home_content2_item">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lkb1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' OnCommand="lkbDestaque_Command" OnClientClick="return PostToNewWindow();">
        <% if (language() == "pt-BR") %>
        <% { %>
        <%# Eval("Title") %>
        <% } %>
        <% if (language() == "es-CL") %>
        <% { %>
        <%# Eval("Title_es") %>
        <% } %>
        <% if (language == "en-GB") %>
        <% { %>
        <%# Eval("Title_en") %>
        <% } %>
      </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

with the following javascript:

```
function PostToNewWindow() {
    originalTarget = document.forms[0].target;
    document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
    window.setTimeout("document.forms[0].target=originalTarget;", 600);
    return true;
}
```

The strange thing is that the PostBack command don’t work for the first button, but works just fine for the other ones.

I’m getting this error when clicking the first button: “_dopostback error in null or undefined not a function object”.

Have you guys ever had a problem like that? Does someone have any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) are for **runnable** examples in-browser. Your examples aren't runnable, so just use code blocks (`{}`). *(I've fixed it for you.)*

Comment: Note that unless you've declared `originalTarget` in your client-side JavaScript somewhere, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my blog)*; be sure to declare your variables. Also, don't use strings in `setTimeout`. Instead: http://pastebin.com/xEdvpzs5

Comment: Thanks a lot for fix the post and for the tips!! Unfortunately, even changing the JavaScript as you told me, I still get the error message when clicking in the first button while the others work.